# Object being returned from Controller is Null On Server. When running locally the object returns

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

**Resolved..Found out it was an issue between server permissions vs local. The server was running as a different user and didn't have all the explicit permissions needed to execute the stored procedures.**

I have an mvc application that is doing a get action. The controller returns a JSON object. Then in the javascript side there is a generic JS class that displays the object into the user interface.

The problem is, when deploying this application on the server, running the get returns the error. Whereas running this locally it acts as intended.

Is there some way I can debug what is going on on the controller side or atleast throw some exception?

Here is the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetMessageLog(string address)
    {
        List<MessageErrorLog> results = _logicHelper.GetMesseageErrorLogByInput(address);

        if (results == null)
            return Json(new MessageErrorLog(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json(results.Select(x => new
        {
            LogId = x.LogId
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The Form:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("GetMessageLog", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "messagelog-form", onsubmit = "SearchAndWriteRecordsWithActions(event, this, WriteSearchResultsWithButtonForAction, AddToRow)" }))
        {
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address" id="address" />

            <button id="messageLog-submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="ClearSearch()">Search</button><br /><br />
        }
```

and here is the JS callback:

```
    WriteSearchResultsWithButtonForAction: function (list, $output, addToRowCallback) {
    ADMIN.Log("WriteSearchResults", JSON.stringify(list));
    if (list == null) {
        alert("No object returned when it should have one");
    }
```

The problem is above.. the list object is null. Locally, it is not. On the server it is.

In other areas of this application I am using very similar functionality and that works fine on the server. So I am a bit stumped as to why this is returning a NULL object from the controller.

Comment: Have you tried to assign data from select to some variable and then send this variable in JSON ? Just to check if results.Select isn't null

Comment: Yep, just tried returning the object itself and no luck. I'll modify the controller code to show the get data as its not too much more code.

Comment: so 'result' is null or   result.Select()  returns null ?

Comment: Nope. There is data in result. I also just ran a separate case...results.Add(new MessageErrorLog() { LogId = 1, OrderNumber = "Test", ErrorMessage = "Error message" }); and returned the object. Still the same error message. Not sure how its 'losing' the object returning the view. I thought it may had to do with the methods attribute or the json request behavior but those are set.

Comment: Updated OP with resolution.